# Ros communicate via rs232

Tags: ros, servo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have servos that communiate via rs232 and I was wondering if anybody knew of any ros libraries or packages that can communicate with devices over rs232. I looked at rosserial, and I think it is aimed toward arduino, so probably not what I want. Any advice? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206701/ros-communicate-via-rs232/) by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2015-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-04-06**:
Worth looking at this QA thread http://answers.ros.org/question/84821/how-to-use-serial-port-in-ros/

**Comment by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) on 2015-04-06**:
Thanks! I was looking at the rosserial_python package, that just might do what I want if I use some rs232 to usb converters. I can specify the ports in the launch file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-07**:
@jbrown: `rosserial_python` is actually a pkg that implements a bridge over a RS232 link that allows embedded devices to use the ROS pub/sub and svc model to communicate with a full ROS system without having to install full ROS on the embedded device. It is not a generic RS232 library for Python&ROS

**Comment by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) on 2015-04-07**:
Thanks! That does help me understand the python library better. I guess there isn't a generic rs232 library then. At one time, ros communicated with these servos via usb to rs232 converters.

**Comment by [yuanye](https://answers.ros.org/users/32405/yuanye/) on 2017-10-26**:
Hi jbrown, I want to use ROS to control a robot arm by  RS232C.  Did you find out how to communicate via rs232?  thank you

**Comment by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) on 2017-10-27**:
@yuanye: The previous comment from gvdhoorn is pretty good advice, it can communicate with a device over RS232 without ROS being installed on the device (Thanks gvdhoorn!). I like using `rosserial_python` myself. It may take some reading and trail and error, but there are tutorials and code samples.

**Comment by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) on 2017-10-27**:
There is a ROS Wiki page for rosserial if you google it, it is informative and helpful. I would also recommend that you look for sample code that uses rosserial as well as the Wiki page, the sample code will show you how to use `rosserial_python` in your code. What kind of robot arm are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I guess there isn't a generic rs232 library then. At one time, ros communicated with these servos via usb to rs232 converters.

There is a 'generic' ROS serial communication library, it is called [serial](http://wiki.ros.org/serial). It's C++ only though.

For Python you could take a look at what `rosserial_python` itself uses.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) on 2015-04-07**:
Yea, that just might work! Thanks! Should you git clone into a catkin_ws and catkin_make, or build it like they said?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-08**:
No. Assuming you use a Ubuntu release (or derivative), you should install it using `apt-get`. More precisely: `sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRO-serial`. Only install things from source if you need to.